# DotNetZip Hangs Intermittently

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I have a VERY simple program using DotNetZip (most current version) with C#.Net, VS2010. It has begun hanging when it tries to save the file it has zipped up. No error messages, no nothing. It ran fine for a long time, then suddenly started showing this intermittent symptom. I run it using a batch system on MS Server 2003, but I test it on Win7. Both systems yield the intermittent failure. Fails about 80% of the time.

Ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Ionic.Zip;

namespace ZipUpSourceFiles
    {
    class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            string YYYYMMM = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MMM");
            string TargetPath = @"\\winntdom\root\common\xxx\secure\Construction\Access\All Database Backup\" + YYYYMMM + @"_Backup\";
            string SourcePath = @"\\winntdom\root\common\xxx\secure\Construction\Access\YYYY\";
            string ZipName=DateTime.Today.ToString("yy-MM-dd") + @".zip";
            string ZipWithPath = TargetPath + ZipName;

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(TargetPath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Creating Directory");
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(TargetPath);
                }
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(ZipWithPath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleting file"); 
                    System.IO.File.Delete(ZipWithPath);
                }
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Zipping up Directories");
                    zip.AddDirectory(SourcePath); // recurses subdirectories
                    Console.WriteLine("Saving Directories {0}",ZipName);
                    zip.Save(ZipWithPath);
                    Console.WriteLine("Finishing Up");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is your storage and NW throughput to \\winntdom?  Have you considered copying the files locally, zipping locally and copying back?

Comment: It is an open source project so you can just debug it yourself.  If you don't want to then just use another library, there are plenty.

Comment: To me, it is simply an expected result. Compression is expensive, and so is copying via UNC. If it does not hang, then I would be surprised.

Comment: switch to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx if you are on .net 4.5+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some further googling, I found a reference that suggesting increasing buffer size properties. I did that, and it's working.

```
zip.BufferSize = 1000000;
zip.CodecBufferSize = 1000000;
```